# ASP.NET MVC list one person multiple locations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that runs off of a one table database. It is a small contact list with rows like first name, last name, number, ect. Right now, the list will show one doctor in two different rows because they have two different locations. I want to make it so that on the index page, it will just show the name once and under it there will be the two different locations.

Also, when the user goes to add or edit a doctor, I want them to be able to add two different locations. Right now there is only one spot to add the location a doctor works at.

I did look at this link:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

But I am wondering if there is a more simple way since my application runs off of only one table. This example also uses check boxes, and I want there to be text boxes to type out the location. The application is in production so I don't want to have to recreate the database to normalize the table.

Thanks for any help

Edit:
I will also need to be able to add separate phone numbers to the separate locations as well

Comment: so, in your table the same doctor can be listed twice?  can't you simply group them?

Comment: In the index? Would that also take the multiple locations to the details page? And I also need to have multiple spots for locations in the add doctor page

Comment: As @Dean.DePue said, you could group the results before sending to your view. As for allowing multiple locations when creating a doctor, make the location property of your view model a `List<string>` or whatever. Then your view can bind to the list so your controller has knowledge of each location and can insert multiple records.

Comment: It sounds like you are going to want a different table that you can associate to each person record. Assuming there is an unlimited number of phone numbers and/or locations a Doctor can be associated to then this would be the best way to pull it off (PK/FK relationship between tables). I understand that would be tricky to pull off without normalizing the DB, but you are going to have a maintenance mess to resort to a "hacky" solution. For the doctor thing I think a group by is what you are looking for as @Dean.DePue mentioned.

Comment: How can I sweep my house with a tooth brush? Should I go and by a broom instead? Mmmmm... yep, you can kneel down and sweep your house with a terrible effort. That's possible. But I'd rather buy a broom. Take into account that he main problem is not reading and grouping the data, but inserting / updating /deleting the location and phone numbers is the worst part.